# Appium POM java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15.proxyClassLookup()

Tags: java, appium, pageobjects

Setting up appium on my new mac. When executed a Test am seeing below error,

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15.proxyClassLookup()
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.prepareAnnotationMethods(AppiumByBuilder.java:85)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.getFilledValue(AppiumByBuilder.java:92)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.createBy(AppiumByBuilder.java:148)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.getBys(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:133)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildMobileNativeBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:182)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:216)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:66)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:53)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:56)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)

JAVA VERSION:
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)

Appium Desktop Version: 1.20.2

```
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this situation by changing from Java SE 17.0.1 to Java SE 11.0.12. Please, see the following picture.
[Press here to see the change in Elipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2O2u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn clean install`, if it doesn't help try reset cache in Intellij